# How to Change Format column in Datagridview to date type for this value

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcolumn

For example, I have a value like this :

```
41607.2069444444; 41607.2068402778; 41607.2072222222;
```

this is calculation of dateTimeOrigination from CDR, in excel where i change the format cell to type date, its work and this is 11/29/2013  4:58:42 AM. My questions is how to format this value to date in datagridview in VB.net?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this:

```
MyDatagridview.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

In my case the 5th column (Remember that Datagridview.Columns are zero-based) is Date-Type
Let me know if it helped you :)