# How to change 6 digit number into Date String

Tags: vb.net, date, datagridview, format

So, I've found this thread, which talks about my issue exactly, however the solution doesn't work for me: [How to Change Format column in Datagridview to date type for this value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749542/how-to-change-format-column-in-datagridview-to-date-type-for-this-value)

I've got a different number patter, in which my data is: YYMMDD, just 6 numerical digits (000901 - September 1st, 2000)

Does the data structure make a difference when converting it to a data string? Does it need to be in an initial format?

This is my current string of code:

`DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yy/MM/dd"`

Just trying to get any format what-so-ever, but it just remains as 6 digits.

Comment: Does the data come from a file or database? I'm thinking that it might be better/easier to change the data type at the earliest point rather than on the DataGridView for this particular format

Comment: The data is basically from a .log file (or plain text), I'm using fixed width delimiters to parse the file out, and one set of the data that is pulled out, is a date, the other is time stamp, which I'll also need converted to time format.

Comment: I've also tried ```CDate(DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd")``` but I get an error saying the ```System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "000901" to type 'Date' is not valid.'```

Comment: what about `dt as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("000901", "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` then when you display it just set the format in `dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try this. Set your format in the datagridview to the date format you want to use. For my example, I had 3 columns and the far right column contained the 6 digit strings.

[image]

In my 3rd column I set a format of yyyy/MM/dd in the datagridview.

In the button click I looped through the dgv and parsed the values to a datetime which allowed the format to work as it was now working with a date type.

```
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not r.IsNewRow Then
            r.Cells(2).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(r.Cells(2).Value.ToString, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        End If
    Next
```

Upon clicking the button, I got the following results.

[image]

Now that the column is a date datatype, we can just change the format and the columns format to the new format setting.

I added a second button and in that button I placed the code

```
DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MMM dd, yyyy"
```

which immediately change the 3rd column to the new format

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful, simple and elegant, and works a treat! I was easily able to adapt this to work with time as well. Much appreciated!!! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

After some thought and experimentation, I realised how to do this on the GUI instead of when loading the data.
You can achieve this particular formatting by handling the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView`.

Test Data I used:

```
Private Property MyData As DataTable

Private Sub InitialiseData()
    MyData = New DataTable
    MyData.Columns.Add("YMDString", GetType(String))

    Dim dr As DataRow

    dr = MyData.NewRow()
    dr(0) = "000901"
    MyData.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = MyData.NewRow()
    dr(0) = "010901"
    MyData.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = MyData.NewRow()
    dr(0) = "020901"
    MyData.Rows.Add(dr)
End Sub
```

DataGridView configuration

```
Private Sub SetupDataGridView()
    InitialiseData()
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("YMDString", "YMD String")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("YMDDateTime", "YMD DateTime")
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "YMDString"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "YMDString"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MyData

    AddHandler DataGridView1.CellFormatting, AddressOf DataGridView1OnCellFormatting
End Sub
```

And the `CellFormatting` event handler that does the hard work. The `DateTime` parsing isn't the best you can use, but it does illustrate the principal of what you want to achieve.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1OnCellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
    Dim thisGrid As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)

    If (thisGrid IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing) Then
        If (thisGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "YMDDateTime") Then
            Dim stringValue As String = e.Value.ToString()
            Dim year As Integer = 2000 + stringValue.Substring(0, 2)
            Dim month As Integer = stringValue.Substring(2, 2)
            Dim day As Integer = stringValue.Substring(4, 2)

            Dim dt As New DateTime(year, month, day)

            e.Value = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When run, I get this result:

[image: When run, I get this result:]

Answer (score 0):

I took your six digit string and converted to a DateTime then formatted as you wished.

```
Dim strDate As String = "180211"
Dim myDate As New DateTime(CInt("20" & strDate.Substring(0, 2)), CInt(strDate.Substring(2, 2)), CInt(strDate.Substring(4)))
Debug.Print(myDate.ToString("yy/MM/dd"))
```

EDIT:
I found a better answer thanks to user1751825 at [VB.NET compare date time from string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094018/vb-net-compare-date-time-from-string-format)

```
Dim myDate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```